set token in HTTP header in Fatfree framework Testing mock()
I'm inexperienced in Testing and I want to test routes in my fat-free framework project. Based on the fat-free document I can use $f3->mock(). For testing routes like the following code I should pass the user token(JWT Token) in Headers as Authorization.(in postman I set JWT token in Authorization key in Headers tab).
in the following code I want to test route /user/info. I should send user_id as a post|get params and JWT token in header.
 $f3->mock('POST /user/info', array('user_id' => '1'), array('Authorization' =>  $token);

I also set the header in $f3 like the following :
 $token= "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO....";
 $f3->set('HEADERS.Authorization', $token);

After executing my test file. i didn't get the desired response. If pass the jwt token to the route, it returns the user data. if not returns an empty JSON.
Is the a problem with the mock() function that doesn't set the Authorization in header or something wrong in my code?
